# Cast an Explicit ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-structures, casting, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection of an object in C#.  This object implements an interface.  I would like to be able to convert the ObservableCollection of the object to an ObservableCollection of the interface without having to parse through the collection.

So for example:

I have an object "Guitar" which implements an interface called "IMusicalInstrument".  I bind an ObservableCollection of Guitar objects to MyListBox.  I want the following line of code to be able to convert listbox itemsSource to an ObservableCollection.

```
    ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument> InstrumentList = 
(ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument>)MyListBox.ItemsSource;
```

Currently, that is giving me an InvalidCastException.

Is there a way to accomplish this (without having to parse through the collection)?

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `MyListBox.ItemsSource` is an instance of `ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument>`, then no, you cannot cast it.

Answer (score 3):

You can not cast it however one approach is to wrap your iteration which I know you want to avoid but unfortunately can't into an [extension method](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/ienumerabletoobservablecollection/).

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerableList)
    {
        if (enumerableList != null)
        {
            //create an emtpy observable collection object
            var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();

            //loop through all the records and add to observable collection object
            foreach (var item in enumerableList)
                observableCollection.Add(item);

            //return the populated observable collection
            return observableCollection;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do something like...

```
ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument> InstrumentList = MyListBox.ItemsSource.ToObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument>();
```

...which is what I believe you are after.

You can also simply pass the `IEnumerable<T>` reference into the constructor of `ObservableCollection<T>`...

```
ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument> InstrumentList = new ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument>(MyListBox.ItemsSource);
```

Comment: ObservableCollection already has a constructor that does this.

Comment: This of course does not provide notifications from the source, just a new observable collection with the original as the source for the items.

Comment: @Steve `To...` generally returns a new instance; `ToList`, `ToArray` and so forth. The newly returned `ObservableCollection` would obviously provide all the notifications that accompany that type once you begin to use the new instance. If you plan to continue to use the backing `IEnumerable` that would as expected, not work.

Comment: Indeed - I just got the impression from the question that he wanted a kind of "pipeline" where the type of the item in the collection was changed, but the notifications continued to be provided. I have had such requirements before (that's how I ended up here :)).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't do this, because an `ObservableCollection<Guitar>` can't be treated as an `ObservableCollection<IMusicalInstrument>` -- e.g. you can't call `collection.Add(new Flute())` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just manage items of the collection, then you can try to cast ItemsSource to non-generic IList.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ObservableCollection simply to handle collection changed events, you could cast to INotifyCollectionChanged and add your event handler. The INotifyCollectionChanged does not use generics, so you would have to cast in your event handler anyhow.

However, if you want to enumerate your collection of IMusicalInstrument instances, you can use the Linq Cast() extension method. e.g.

```
IEnumerable<IMusicalInstrument> instruments = 
     ((IEnumerable)MyListBox.ItemsSource).Cast<IMusicalInstrument>();
```

Hope that helps!